# Error loading example PostgreSQL database: "Could not find header for file ..."

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore

I am learning o use PostgreSQL so I am trying to insert a whole practice database **"dvdrental"**, which I downloaded from [PostgreSQL learning blog](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/). I am on a Mac OSX and I am using PostgreSQL through my terminal (and ZSH).

**These are the steps I took:**

1. download dvdrental.zip file
2. create dvdrental database under the right user, with the right permissions
3. unzipped dvdrental.zip
4. tar-ed the folder that I extracted from .zip file

Here is an `ls -l` output of that is inside the extracted directory:

```
2163.dat
2165.dat
2167.dat
2168.dat
2169.dat
2171.dat
2173.dat
2175.dat
2177.dat
2179.dat
2181.dat
2183.dat
2185.dat
2187.dat
2189.dat
restore.sql
toc.dat
```

Here is the command that I am using to get the sample db dump into my newly created db:

```
~>pg_restore -U postgres -d weather /users/edchigliak/downloads/dvdrental.tar
```

**The error I receive:**

```
~>pg_restore: [tar archiver] could not find header for file "toc.dat" in tar archive
```

Comment: `pg_restore --format=t -U postgres -d weather dvdrental.tar` works for me (do **not** untar `dvdrental.tar` - keep it as a single file)

Comment: Fortunately, that blog carefully describes how to do this. Read http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/load-postgresql-sample-database/

Answer (score 4):

restore.sql is a plain SQL statement file in your "dvdrental.tar" file. First create your db with the statement below;

```
CREATE DATABASE db_name ENCODING = 'UTF8';
```

After that, instead of using pg_restore you can use psql.

```
psql --echo-all --file=restore.sql db_name
```

Comment: Hi i think the command is missing -- ```psql --echo-all --file=restore.sql db_name```